# Extending Directives in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-directive, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I'm trying to extend `NgbPopover` in order to dispatch a custom action when the popover's `open` or `close` methods are called.

I have the following set up:

`custom-popover.directive.ts`

```
@Directive({  
    selector:'[customPopover]',
    exportAs:'customPopover'
}) 
export class CustomPopover extends NgbPopover {}
```

`some-list.component.ts`

```
<input #quantityInput
       (input)="onInputChange()"
       type="number"

       popoverTitle="Warning!"
       [customPopover]="validationError"
       #validationPopovers="customPopover">

<ng-template #validationError>{{ message }}</ng-template>
```

I expect this to behave like the original NgbPopover(allowing me to override the `open` and `close` methods if I so wish), but instead I get the following error:

`Can't bind to 'customPopover' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.`

EDIT (to show declarations/imports in modules):

`custom-popover.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CustomPopover
    ],
    imports: [
        NgbModule
    ],
    exports:[CustomPopover]
})
export class CustomPopoverModule { }
```

`app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       ...
       CustomPopoverModule
    ],
    ...
})
```

`some-list.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        NgbModule,
        CustomPopoverModule
    ],
    ...
})
```

Comment: You probably didn't add it to `declarations: [...]` and `exports: [...]` of a module or not imported the module where you are using it.

Comment: Edited to show declarations and exports.  I'll admit that I was fighting with those for a while before I got the final error (seemingly) from the template.  But those errors usually complained about `[customPopover]` not being exported.

Comment: Still can't find a mistake. Can you try to reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I found the issue.  In addition to supplying `selector` and `exportAs` properties, one also needs to add an `Input()` string that corresponds with the selector in order to apply `[customPopover]` to an element, so the directive becomes:

```
@Directive({  
    selector:'[customPopover]',
    exportAs:'customPopover'
}) 
export class CustomPopover extends NgbPopover {
    @Input()
    customPopover: string;
}
```

Comment: was following this example but was not able to succeed. Do you have plunker or something with working solution?

Comment: no worries i got solution! Thanks for reply, anyway 

Comment: @Micko, Could you share your solution plz

Comment: @azerafati here is link to my question and also there is accepted answer that i posted :) Let me know if you have some questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010439/extend-ng-boostrap-popover-component-with-custom-angular-directive